# populating the neccessary data in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getSampleData();
  }

  getSampleData(){ 
   console.log('enter value');
    this.setState({
      sampleData:{
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr',
                  'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
                   'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: '2017',
                data: [92, 50, 33, 70, 122, 22, 21,20, 22, 215, 278, 190],

            },
            {
              label: '2018',
              data: [22, 210, 520, 278, 260, 245, 221,516, 718, 174, 154, 148],

          },
        ]
    }} );
    /// Here i want to get monthdata that to be taken from sampleData
monthData:
   //for example this month 221 should come here,from the sampleData
    console.log('end value');


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos:</h2>
       <p> monthData</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am new to React.js.But i am unable to put particualr month data while displaying in the tags. Though I referred monthData word here, I am not having proper knowledge on variables referring(sampleData) and getting data out of that in the html. Directly making the particualr month value in p tag from sampleData is also fine to me, without using monthData variable. Can any one help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Component state is available via the `state` member of the instance, which is just a plain object (containing whatever you put into the state via `setState`). So for example in your `render` method you could grab your datasets via `this.state.datasets`. To insert any variable into JSX (the html-looking syntax in your `render` method) you just use curly braces (e.g. `<p>{myVariable}</p>`).

Comment: @user533 how you want to render it ? Data of the current year and month ? or All the data of current month in every year ?

Comment: @SubhanshuPandey Data of current month of the current year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly filter the data from the datasets of the current year. You can get the current year by using `new Date().getFullYear()` and current month using `new Date().getMonth()`.Filter will return a array

1.`this.state.sampleData.datasets.filter((dataset) => dataset.label == new Date().getFullYear())`  this statement will give you the filter object of the current year in **datasets** key

2.`filteredArray[0].data[new Date().getMonth()]` will give you the data of the current month.

```
    render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <p>
        // Jul : 221 in this case
        {this.state.sampleData.labels[new Date().getMonth()]} : 
        {this.state.sampleData.datasets.filter((dataset) => dataset.label == new Date().getFullYear())[0].data[new Date().getMonth()]}  
       </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/Subhanshu/n5u2wwjg/76470/

```
var data  = { labels:['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],datasets:[{label:'2017',data:[92,50,33,70,122,22,21,20,22,215,278,190],},{label:'2018',data:[22,210,520,278,260,245,221,516,718,174,154,148],}]}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        sampleData: "",
      currentMonth : new Date().getMonth() ,
      currentYear : new Date().getFullYear(),
      monthData : "",
    }
  }


  componentWillMount(){
    this.getSampleData();
  } 

  getSampleData(){
  var self = this;
  this.setState({  sampleData :  data},()=>{
    var filteredArray = this.state.sampleData.datasets.filter((dataset) => dataset.label == this.state.currentYear)
    var monthData = filteredArray[0].data[this.state.currentMonth]
        this.setState({ monthData : monthData })
    })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <p>
              {this.state.sampleData.labels[this.state.currentMonth]} :  {this.state.monthData}
       </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Cant we use one variable like sampleData that to just display in p tag, and move the logic to getSampleData, It is just a thought to see how all logics and variables are used in getSampleData method.

Comment: could you please do that...that will help me to understand how to proceed to different circumstances

Comment: @user533 yes sure. Please look at this updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Subhanshu/n5u2wwjg/77718/    is this helps you ? I have now  used the same logic at the call back of the setState of sampleData.

Comment: Thanks...great help

Answer (score 1):

Here I've got the data based on the current month. Likewise, you may change it to year if you want dynamic one. Please check the updated snippet below:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getSampleData();
  }

  getSampleData(){
   console.log('enter value');
    this.setState({
      sampleData:{
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr',
              'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
               'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        datasets: [
        {
            label: '2017',
            data: [92, 50, 33, 70, 122, 22, 21,20, 22, 215, 278, 190],

        },
        {
          label: '2018',
          data: [22, 210, 520, 278, 260, 245, 221,516, 718, 174, 154, 148],

        },
      ]
    }} );
    /// Here i want to get monthdata that to be taken from sampleData
    monthData:
   //for example this month 221 should come here,from the sampleData
   console.log('end value');


  }

  render() {
    const d = new Date();
    const m = d.getMonth();
    const monthData = this.state.sampleData.datasets[1].data[m];
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos:</h2>
        <p>Current Month data : {monthData}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here **data[m]** represents the current month(**6 - July**).

Comment: Thanks @Arul your inputs helped me a lot...:)

Comment: @user533 Welcome  :-)